# How to check Hubot log output in test script

Tags: testing, logging, coffeescript, mocha.js, hubot

I'm writing a test for my Hubot (which acts as a Slack bot). Triggered by certain Slack messages, the bot sends an HTTP POST request to a separate Rails app. How can I check in my test script that the HTTP request has been sent? My guess was that I should check the contents of the `robot.logger` (please let me know if there's a better way) - but if so, how can I access the log in the test?

**Hubot script** (basically, it informs the Rails app about a user who is leaving the office to take a break):

```cs
module.exports = (robot) ->
  robot.respond /off to lunch/i, (res) ->
    res.reply('Later alligator')
    robot.logger.info "This user is going on lunch break: #{res.message.user.id}"

    data = JSON.stringify({
      slack_user_id: res.message.user.id
    })
    robot.http(process.env.RAILS_APP_URL + '/break')
      .header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
      .post(data) (err, resp, body) ->
        if err
          robot.logger.info "Encountered an error. #{err}"
          res.reply('Sorry, there was an error recording your break time')
        else
          robot.logger.info 'Successfully sent HTTP POST request to Rails app'
```

**Log output when I execute this script:**

```sh
INFO This user is going on lunch break: [SLACK_USER_ID]
INFO Successfully sent HTTP POST request to Rails app
```

As I mentioned above, I'd like to check in my test script that the HTTP request was sent, by asserting that the log is going to include the message `'Successfully sent HTTP POST request to Rails app'`. However, I don't know how to access the Hubot's log in my test. I thought it would have something to do with `process.stdout` because the bot logs to stdout, but I couldn't get it to work.

**Test script:**

```cs
Helper = require('hubot-test-helper')
helper = new Helper('../scripts/break-start.coffee')
request = require('request')
expect = require('chai').expect
nock = require('nock')

describe 'bot responds to user message and sends ', ->
  beforeEach ->
    # Set up the room before running the test.
    @room = helper.createRoom()

    # Set up a request interceptor.
    nock(process.env.RAILS_APP_URL)
      .post('/break', { slack_user_id: 'bob' })
      .reply(200)

  afterEach ->
    # Tear down the room after the test to free up the listener.
    @room.destroy()

  context 'user sends lunch message', ->
    beforeEach ->
      @room.user.say('bob', '@hubot Off to lunch')

    it 'responds to users who are off to lunch', ->
      expect(@room.messages).to.eql [
        ['bob', '@hubot Off to lunch']
        ['hubot', '@bob Later alligator']
      # I want to do something like this:
      # expect(robot.log).include('Successfully sent HTTP POST request to Rails app')
```

Of course, I can see in the console log when I run the test that the HTTP request is being sent, but I'd also like to assert it so that the test fails if the request is not sent.

**Log output when test is executed:**

```
INFO This user is going on lunch break: bob
✓ responds to users who are off to lunch
INFO Successfully sent HTTP POST request to Rails app
```

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't advise writing tests depending on logs. The log is a side-effect of the program. If you change the log output, the tests will fail, even though the functionality is still correct.

Instead you should use a library to mock out and check if the http request was performed. Actually making the request would be a side-effect, and again shouldn't be done in your tests (what if you cause excessive load on an external service due to tests running?

You are already using the `nock` library to catch the request. It can also be used to check if the request was made (see the [expectations docs](https://github.com/nock/nock#expectations) from the nock repo).

Here is an example using the `requestScope.done()` from nock in your test.

```
it 'sends the break request to the rails server', ->
  # capture the request to the rails app
  railsRequest = nock(process.env.RAILS_APP_URL)
    .post('/break', { slack_user_id: 'bob' })
    .reply(200)
  # make the request and wait for it to be completed
  await @room.user.say('bob', '@hubot Off to lunch')
  # check that the request was made
  railsRequest.done()
```

I'm using `await` to ensure the function call which should make the request is completed before testing for it. If you're not familiar with `await`, you can move the check (`railsRequest.done()`) into a `.then()` promise handler on the `@room.user.say(...)` call instead.

---

### Promise version:

Regarding your comment, here is the promisified version. You need to pass `.then` a function. If you pass it `.then request.done()` then the `request.done()` expectation will be executed immediately and its result will be passed as the promise callback. Either wrap it in another function (see below) or remove the parenthesis (`.then request.done`). But be careful with the second option. If your promise returns a value, this will be passed to the callback. As it's from a library, this may cause unexpected behaviour - that's why I would suggest the first option:

```
it 'sends the break request to the rails server', ->
  # capture the request to the rails app
  railsRequest = nock(process.env.RAILS_APP_URL)
    .post('/break', { slack_user_id: 'bob' })
    .reply(200)
  # make the request and wait for it to be completed
  @room.user.say('bob', '@hubot Off to lunch').then ->
    # check that the request was made
    railsRequest.done()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought using `await` necessitates a function with the keyword `async`. Since there was no `async`, the code you suggested returned `ReferenceError: await is not defined`. Is there a way to use `async/await` here?

Comment: I also tried using a `.then` promise, and this worked:
`@room.user.say('bob', '@hubot Off to lunch').then(@railsRequest.isDone())`.


But if I swap out `isDone()` with `done()`, I get an `AssertionError` saying `Mocks not yet satisfied`. Not sure why even if I read the [docs](https://github.com/nock/nock#expectations), since the difference seems to be "all specified calls vs single", but there's only one mock here to start with. Sorry for the multiple questions and thanks again!